# PHP setcookie returns false when used with thinkphp framework

Tags: php, setcookie, thinkphp

`setcookie` doesn't work when I use with thinkphp framework. just `$a = setcookie('a','a');` no path no domain. `var_dump($a)` returns `bool(false);` no output before this, and no warning.

but when I didn't use the framework , it works.

Comment: Try to enable `error_reporting` and make sure no header is sent before `setcookie`.

Answer (score 3):

The [documentation for `setcookie()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) says that "If output exists prior to calling this function, setcookie() will fail and return FALSE."  So be sure to put `setcookie()` before any statements that might write to STDOUT.

When this happens, PHP will log a warning in your error log:  "PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by..."  So check your error log file.

Comment: but it doesn't warn anything. i think it would make some warning if anything output before setcookie. thank you.

Comment: It will log a warning in your error log:  "PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by..."  Check your error log file.

Answer (score 0):

You must set cookies before sending any data. Before any echo and so on. So framework maybe have its own cookie handler. Check its documentation.

Or you can use extension:

```
<?php
// +----------------------------------------------------------------------
// | ThinkPHP [ WE CAN DO IT JUST THINK IT ]
// +----------------------------------------------------------------------
// | Copyright (c) 2009 http://thinkphp.cn All rights reserved.
// +----------------------------------------------------------------------
// | Licensed ( http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0 )
// +----------------------------------------------------------------------
// | Author: liu21st <liu21st@gmail.com>
// +----------------------------------------------------------------------
// $Id$

/**
 +------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Cookie管理类
 +------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * @category   Think
 * @package  Think
 * @subpackage  Util
 * @author    liu21st <liu21st@gmail.com>
 * @version   $Id$
 +------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */
class Cookie extends Think
{
    static function is_set($name) {
        return isset($_COOKIE[C('COOKIE_PREFIX').$name]);
    }

    static function get($name) {
        $value   = $_COOKIE[C('COOKIE_PREFIX').$name];
        $value   =  unserialize(base64_decode($value));
        return $value;
    }

    static function set($name,$value,$expire='',$path='',$domain='') {
        if($expire=='') {
            $expire =   C('COOKIE_EXPIRE');
        }
        if(empty($path)) {
            $path = C('COOKIE_PATH');
        }
        if(empty($domain)) {
            $domain =   C('COOKIE_DOMAIN');
        }
        $expire =   !empty($expire)?    time()+$expire   :  0;
        $value   =  base64_encode(serialize($value));
        setcookie(C('COOKIE_PREFIX').$name, $value,$expire,$path,$domain);
        $_COOKIE[C('COOKIE_PREFIX').$name]  =   $value;
    }

    static function delete($name) {
        Cookie::set($name,'',time()-3600);
        unset($_COOKIE[C('COOKIE_PREFIX').$name]);
    }

    static function clear() {
        unset($_COOKIE);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Note that the `Cookie` object still is just using `setcookie()` under the hood (see the `set()` method), so you still need to make sure that you don't send any output before setting the cookie.

Answer (score 0):

use cookie("name", "value", time)

time is optional, second

Comment: you should explain *why* that would solve the problem

Answer (score -3):

cuz,thinkphp rewrite a function cookie,if you want to use cookie with thinkphp.you should write cookie(name,value),no more setcookie!

from China
QQ:1720036678